# Amazon EMR - Spark Web UI for Thrift server queries

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster for running Spark code using Zeppelin and occasionally I run SQL queries using the JDBC interface provided by Spark thrift server. The queries are running fine and I am able to see the results but I am not able to see the Spark UI for the queries executed using Spark thrift server.

When I use Zeppelin, I can see the application in YARN resource manager and Spark History server. But the queries I run using the thrift server don't show up anywhere. It is understandable that they don't show up in YARN resource manager but it is surprising to not see them in Spark HistoryServer as well. Where can I see the details of the SQL queries executed using Spark thrift server in EMR?

Comment: How is it that you are running the Spark Thriftserver? (I ask because, though it's possible to start yourself, EMR does not yet officially support it.) The Spark Thriftserver does run as a YARN application, so you should be able to get to the Spark UI for it just like you would for Zeppelin or any other Spark application.

Comment: @JonathanKelly I am using 5.3.1 and thrift server starts up automatically and is using port 10000. I am not starting it manually. I was suspecting EMR might not be supporting it. Do you have references to this in the documentation?

Comment: Ah, OK, I thought that might be the case. What you are hitting is not the Spark Thriftserver but Hiveserver2. This is why you can't see any YARN application. Your queries are running directly on Hive (using Tez as the execution engine), not on Spark.

Comment: @JonathanKelly Thanks! It makes sense now. As spark thrift also uses hiveserver2, I used Hive server jdbc drivers to connect and since the queries were running fine, I deluded myself to think it was Spark running the queries.